# mongodb 3.4.3 Permission denied wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267 error with ubuntu 16

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm having problems lauching mongod as a service:
How is it possible that it works when I do sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf but when launching it with sudo service mongod start I get an error in the log

`Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267`

I'm running mongodb on ubuntu 16

I followed exactly the instructions in the mongodb documentation for installation of that version, so is this a bug? Any suggestions how to solve this are appreciated.

Additional information:

The mongodb service startup script looks like this and runs it as user mongodb, could this be connected to the error? 
lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Service
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> I'm having problems lauching mongod as a service: How is it possible that it works when I do sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf but when launching it with sudo service mongod start I get an error in the log

The `sudo` command starts `mongod` with `root` permissions (aka [superuser access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)). If you run `mongod` as a service the user and group are configured in the service definition (`mongodb` for both in your example).

There is no need to run the `mongod` process as the `root` user, and this is strongly discouraged as per the common security practice of [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

If you want to test a configuration from the command-line, you could use `sudo` to run with a specified user instead of the default (root) user.

For example:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

In general, it's best to use a service configuration rather than running `mongod` manually. With manual invocation you will also have to remember to include parameters like the config file path (as there is no default config path). Without a configuration file, `mongod` also uses default options such as a `dbPath` of `/data/db`.

> Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267

The likely cause of your permission errors is having previously started `mongod` as the `root` user. Some directories and files may now be owned by the root user, so the  `mongodb` user cannot access those. Your specific error relates to accessing files in the data directory (i.e. the configured `storage.dbPath` in `mongod.conf`).

Assuming you haven't changed the default paths in your `mongod.conf` file, you should be able to recursively adjust permissions to match what the `mongod.service` definition expects.

First, ensure you have stopped your `mongod` instance if it is currently running.

Then, recursively adjust permissions to the expected user and group:

```
# storage.dbPath
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb

# systemLog.path
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

Now you should be able to start `mongod` as a service. If the service fails to start, there should be further detail in the `mongod` log file (assuming the log file is writable by the `mongodb` service user).

Comment: Hi, this is an older post but it helped me resolve my issue. Actually I'm new to Linux and I have this same root type problem a lot. I have one root user to connect to my VPS, so then when I install services they are always created by the root user, and I always have to muck about trying to change permissions. What is the right way to install things on Linux? If I'm the root user, how do I tell Linux to install mongdb for example, as the mongodb user? Do I need to first create this user, or?

Comment: @Amir If you follow instructions to install MongoDB via official packages (for example: [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)), the permissions and directories will be setup correctly. The MongoDB service is managed via [`sudo service ... `](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#start-mongodb), but the `mongod` process runs with non-privileged user/group permissions (eg. `mongodb`/`mongodb` on Ubuntu, which will be created if they don't exist when the MongoDB server package is installed).

Comment: That is the tutorial that I followed, but I never have to put `sudo` in front of my commands, because I'm already logged in as root. Should I put `sudo` in front? Is that what's missing in my installs?

Comment: @Amir Sorry, only just noticed your comment here. There's no need to run `sudo` if you are already logged in as root. The purpose of `sudo` is to allow a user account to run with privileges of another account (root by default, although other users can be specified). However, as noted in my answer it is not best practice to run your `mongod` process as the root user: the recommended approach is to run `mongod` using a service configuration. The user for your `mongod` process will need to have read/write permissions to all of the files & directories in the `dbPath` used by `mongod`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that starting mongod as root actually changes some of the file permissions required to start as service. I'd been trying to figure out what the issue was, your explanation made it click as to what was wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Have same problem.

What been in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log:

```
2017-05-13T13:46:41.152+0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (13) [1494658001:152518][15821:0x7fb843803cc0], connection: /var/lib/mongodb/journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002: file-remove: unlink: Permission denied
2017-05-13T13:46:41.159+0700 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267
```

So wee see that something can't remove file "WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002" in /var/lib/mongodb/journal/
So id just gave permissions, i just did:

```
sudo chmod 764 /var/lib/mongodb/journal/
```

If not help, try:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/ && sudo chmod 764 /var/lib/mongodb/journal/
```

Answer (score 6):

There are three set-ups that triggers this kind of problem :

1. MongoDB installation is configured to create database files at a given path and this path does not exist on your current system. This path is called  [dbpath](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) in mongo.

In your case, check if `/data/db` exist. If it doesn't or if it is empty, mongod is trying the wrong dbpath. You need to find it, it's usually under `/var/lib/mongodb`.

Once you found it there's two thing you can do. First, copy all the file from there to `/data/db`. Second, change your dbpath under the mongod.conf file, which is located (in linux) at `/etc/mongod.conf`. Make sure to start mongod with the `--config` specifying the configuration file.

2. MongoDB does not have the permission to read one or more files or directories corresponding to its dbpath.

`chown mongodb:mongodb dbpath -R`.

3. MongoDB is missing WiredTiger.wt . This can happen if you remove files under the dbpath or if there's a device failure. We do it for testing a recovery strategy for example.

If you're sure dbpath is correct and that there's no instance of WiredTiger.wt there. Your database is broken. There are no ways to ensure integrity if you lose this file. Reinstall mongodb by :

`sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`

`sudo rm -r dbpath`

`sudo apt-get install mongodb-org`

Edit :
Or copy dbpath from one of your replicas.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in my mongod.log:

```
2021-09-16T16:06:43.782+0200 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 13: Permission       denied
2021-09-16T16:06:43.782+0200 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595     at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 789
```

So I looked in my dbPath folder (specified in mongodb config file /etc/mongod.conf, section storage:dbPath) and found that same file was owned by root:

```
 WiredTiger.turtle
 WiredTigerLAS.wt 
 journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000112
```

From dbPath folder, using the command below, I change owner and group to mongodb:

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb WiredTiger.turtle WiredTigerLAS.wt journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000112
```

After this, I can start mongodb server as
"service mongod start"
and check its status as
"service mongod status" with output:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-09-16 16:19:47 CEST; 54min ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Main PID: 8459 (mongod)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─8459 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
Sep 16 16:19:47 svi5-ubu16 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

Note that above commands are working as normal user, not as root.

My configuration: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, MongoDB shell version v4.2.1.

Other file or folder owned by mongodb (user and group):

```
/var/log/mongodb
/var/lib/mongodb 
/tmp/mongodb-27028.sock
```

I spent a lot of time in solving this issue, thank you very match to every one has posted here and guided me to solution.

Comment: You are a gem! bro

Answer (score 0):

I wish append a comment to the previous answer, but unfortunately I cannot yet.

I completely agree with the explanation of Stennie. It is exactly what was happened to me.
I've always run mongod as a service but today, because some changes that I've made, I've tried to run the process using `sudo mongod --auth --dbpath /data/mongodb/`.. to test authorizations and db changing location. 
After that the mongod service didn't run anymore, due to this permissions problem.

I've to say that the command `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/mongodb/` didn't immediately fix the problem as expected. I've had to reboot several times, remove the `mongod.lock` file under `/data/mongodb/`, reissue the `sudo chown` command again.. and finally everything gone well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue but with custom log path and data dir.  updating the owner and group access to them did not fix the issue for running as a service
updating the group and owner to mongodb:mongodb works on running mongod by itself  as stated earlier

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

or

```
sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself with the same problem on CentOS, but the permissions look correct, it could be because of SELinux policies. On my system, MongoDB files use a specific SELinux context. The mongod server failed to start, outputting the same permissions errors, until I corrected the SELinux contexts.

If it doesn't exist, create the MongoDB data folder (either /var/lib/mongo or /var/lib/mongodb, check your /etc/mongod.conf file):

```
$ mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb
```

Then try to restore the SELinux contexts:

```
$ restorecon -v /var/lib/mongodb
$ restorecon -v /var/lib/mongodb/*
```

If that still doesn't work, try to apply the contexts directly:

```
$ chcon system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0 /var/lib/mongodb
$ chcon system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0 /var/lib/mongodb/*
```

Verify the contexts are correct:

```
$ ls -lZ -d /var/lib/mongodb
drwxr-xr-x. mongod mongod system_u:object_r:mongod_var_lib_t:s0 /var/lib/mongodb
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /var/lib/mongodb
```

is another solution...

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain how and why this will solve the problem.