# MongoDB not starting after downgrade

Tags: database, mongodb, server

MongoDB automatically updated to 3.6 after doing a system update and was no longer compatible with my old dataset. So I downgraded to 3.4 again, however now the mongo instance won't start at all and exits with error code 100. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi @robertbabington, have you tried removing mongod.lock from temp. Please try once. Also, the error clearly says the files are corrupted try mongodb --repair comand

Comment: Thanks, I got it in the end. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

There were a series of issues piggybacking on one another here, but I sorted this out.

Firstly I reverted from 3.6 to 3.4 by uninstalling Mongo:

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Then I installed the specific version of Mongo:

```
apt-get install mongodb-org=3.4.1 mongodb-org-server=3.4.1 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.1 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.1 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.10
```

Then I deleted the `.lock` files:

```
rm -rf /path/to/mongod.lock
rm -rf /path/to/WiredTiger.lock
```

Next you have to grant permissions to Mongo again:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

(Make sure the `dbpath` is correct in `/etc/mongod.conf`. If you want to make any changes to the `mongod.service` file, do it now, and remember to run `systemctl daemon-reload` to set the changes.)

Then finish updating permissions:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

Now `service mongod start` or `sudo systemctl mongod start` should work.

Here are links to some of the resources I found helpful:

- [Installing Mongo on Ubunut](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Uninstalling MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554521/uninstall-mongodb-from-ubuntu)
- [Installing a specific version of Mongo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197336/how-to-install-specific-mongo-version-from-the-ppa)
- [Setting Mongo file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137250/mongodb-3-4-3-permission-denied-wiredtiger-kv-engine-cpp-267-error-with-ubuntu-1)