# MongoDB service not reading configuration file

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I upgraded MongoDB on my Ubuntu 16.04 web server to 4.0 to get acccess to transactions. For other reasons, I didn't get that to work and putting that on the shelf at the moment, but now I also can't start the MongoDB service without setting a config path explicitly (because my dbs are stored in a custom location), like

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

That also means that I can't run MongoDB as a service, because it apparently seems to be ignoring my startup options as well: (from /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service)

```
#Unit contains the dependencies to be satisfied before the service is started.
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database
After=network.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
# Service tells systemd, how the service should be started.
# Key `User` specifies that the server will run under the mongodb user and
# `ExecStart` defines the startup command for MongoDB server.
[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
# Install tells systemd when the service should be automatically started.
# `multi-user.target` means the server will be automatically started during boot.
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What would be wrong in this case?

Comment: Very likely it's because you ran with `sudo` and the service doesn't, so the data path would be owned by root and the `mongodb` user the service runs under can't access that path anymore.

Comment: @kevinadi Well, you gave me an idea. I checked the logs and it does yes, find the file. Permission error. Then I looked at this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137250/mongodb-3-4-3-permission-denied-wiredtiger-kv-engine-cpp-267-error-with-ubuntu-1

Which also solved the problem, it seems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem was not that MongoDB didn't read the configuration files, but because of permission errors caused by running the service as root initially, which become apparent in the MongoDB log under /var/log/mongodb, where the storage engine WiredTiger failed with error code 13.

[mongodb 3.4.3 Permission denied wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267 error with ubuntu 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137250/mongodb-3-4-3-permission-denied-wiredtiger-kv-engine-cpp-267-error-with-ubuntu-1)