# Trying to restart MongoDB 4.0 after repair facing the following error

Tags: mongodb

Trying to restart MongoDB 4.0 after repair facing the following error

```
 Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
 Reason: 13: Permission denied
 Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 706
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137250/mongodb-3-4-3-permission-denied-wiredtiger-kv-engine-cpp-267-error-with-ubuntu-1):

> the likely cause of your permission errors is having previously
> started mongod as the root user. Some directories and files may now be
> owned by the root user, so the mongodb user cannot access those. Your
> specific error relates to accessing files in the data directory (i.e.
> the configured storage.dbPath in mongod.conf).